# AngularJS $http Authorize header not sent properly to RESTful service when developing locally but works in Cordova

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an iOS application utilizing the Ionic framework with Cordova and have run into a bit of a snag in my dev cycle. While running on my local dev web server, any RESTful call happening from the $http service is failing with a 401 Not Authorized error even though I am passing the `Authorization` header. Interestingly enough, the call works fine once I build the app and deploy onto the iOS Emulator.

FWIW, the api calls are to an Atlassian Confluence api.

CORS doesn't seem to be the issue as that has been configured, tested and working on non-authenticated calls.

Here is the very basic call that is failing within the browser but working on the emulator when using the same headers:

```js
$http.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$http.get('https://www.example.com/rest/prototype/1/search/site?type=blogpost&spaceKey=TESTSPACE&os_authType=basic')
    .success(function (data, status) {
        this.serviceData = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(status, data.result);
    });
```

I am sending two custom headers: `Accept: application/json` and `Authorization: Basic ***` If I run the application in Chrome with the above service configuration, I see the following Request Headers. There is an added Access-Control-Request-Headers that mentions the Accept and Authorization headers, but those headers are not there. I see the following Request Headers going across the wire:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization <!---- This is added but there is no Authorization Header 
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.example.com
Origin:https://local.example-client.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://local.example-client.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
```

If I make the same call with the Authorization Header using the [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) Chrome extension, it works correctly.

```
Accept:application/json <!----------- This one is */* when called from $http
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Authorization:Basic *** REMOVED *** <!----------- This one is missing when called from $http
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: *** REMOVED ***
Host:www.example.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
```

One thing to note is that if I remove the Authorization header line (below), then the `Accept` header  now appears:

```
//$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ************************';
```

Can anyone provide me any insight on what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a problem with your CORS configuration. Authenticated requests require very specific configuration to work properly with CORS.

Make sure you're

- Returning the [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers) header to allow those headers
- Returning the exact origin in [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) (not "*")
- Setting withCredentials to true on the XHR (in Angular this can be set in the defaults just like the headers)

(I'm not entirely sure if the "Authorization" header is considered a "credential" if you set it by hand so the last two may or may not be required.)

The reason it works under Cordova is because Cordova doesn't implement origin restrictions for XHRs (they would be a bit pointless since your app doesn't have anything "local" to communicate with)

Comment: I did a lot more digging and proxying of requests and realized that the implementation of the API is pretty horrible and not at all compatible with CORS. I was able to figure a workaround using the [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to rewrite the request and response headers so at least I can develop locally. Thank you for your insight as it definitely set me in the right direction.